# protractor is closing Chrome browser as soon as browser opened without entering in url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, jasmine2.0

It was working fine and all of sudden it's behaving weird. Opening Chrome with in address bar as "not secure : data:" and not entering in URL.

I have tried updating webdriver-manager update too but no use. Restarting machine.

I am using below versions:

- protractor - 5.1.1
- node v6.10.1
- Chrome 2.29.

Comment: What do you see on the console? Any errors? And a quick shot in the dark: if you have maximize window or browser set size call - comment it out - does it work now?

Comment: no error other than Process exited with error code 1 . no I am not using browser maximize . thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You mention your *chromedriver* version of 2.29, but not your Chrome version. Chrome v56 added some new security features that are likely the issue you're seeing. You can downgrade to Chrome v55 to make sure.

Comment: chrome browser is 58

Comment: even though I downgraded to 55 , it's taking version 58 . any idea how to configure this to 55? thanks

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: MacOS 10.12.3 .